# Migrate from lower version to higher version in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke, migrate

can anyone advise me how to migrate an application in DNN from lower version to higher version

Answer (score 1):

In order to upgrade your DNN installation, upgrade your DNN by steps. Don't make an upgrade which should represent a too big gap, for example from 4.8 to 7.2. A such upgrade will probably fail because it will execute a too large numbers of scripts.
I suggest you to follow those differents steps:

- backup files and the database (if you use the SQL Server Express mode, database is located into your dotnetnuke folder)
- at this step, you could upgrade installed modules in order to avoid exceptions. Take care at the maximum supported version for your current DNN version
- download an upgrade package and unzip the upgrade package at the root of your website with overwriting existing files
- load the website URL (http://www.mywebsite.com for example). It should redirect you on the upgrade wizard. If it doesn't, you also could browse http://www.mywebsite.com/install/install.aspx?mode=upgrade. FYI, in web.config, the "AutoUpgrade" value may block the automatic redirection to the upgrade wizard.
- download an higher upgrade package and do those steps again

Answer (score 0):

Also there is a suggested upgrade path that has been more tested and has fewer upgrade bugs reports. It is at http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/suggested_upgrade_path
There is also some more information about upgrade on that same page.